# Undefined Method Error when Retrieving Recurring Expenses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a small expense management app based on Rails 4.1 and I'm using Ice Cube and Recurring Select gems to create recurring expenses.

The form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@expense) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :amount %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :amount %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :recurring_rules, "no defaults and not set" %><br/>
    <%= f.select_recurring :repeat %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It's a simple scaffold that saves the recurrence rule in this format: `{"interval":1,"until":null,"count":null,"validations":null,"rule_type":"IceCube::DailyRule"}`

I'm trying to list all recurring expenses in the index page itself for the time being. The index action looks like this:

```
 def index
    @expenses = Expense.all
    @exp = @expenses.all_occurrences
  end
```

The corresponding view has the following code:

```
<h2>Recurring Expenses</h2>

<% @exp.each do |e| %>
  <%= e.description %>
  <%= e.amount %>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, I get the undefined method 'all_occurrences' error. I tried using `@exp = @expenses.occurs_on?(Date.today)` in the controller as well, but still I get the undefined method error. Am I missing something here? Do I have to declare something in the model about Ice Cube?

Comment: What is the relationship between Expense and Occurrence so we can suggest some other way to return the wanted objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `@expenses = Expense.all` return a **ActiveRecord_Relation** object to @expenses. And it's an ActiveRecord class, therefore you have no such method called `occurs_on?` or any other custom method in this class.

If you want to get all the Occurrences, and Occurrences is a relationship of Expense, with Expense has_many Occurrences, then this will solve:

```
@occurrences = Expense.occurrences
```

Comment: I was sleepy and made a mistake confusing with the methods. Thanks!